# Sdcard Error After transferring Audio and Video

Tags: android, storage, memory-address, android-memory

I have a problem with my sdcards(3) i can transfer music files and videos from my pc to the memory card. The files are visable and you can view their properties but they fail to play with an error corrupted file yet they play on pc